# stored procedure- Join Query is working in Sql but unable to load in Datagridview C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datagridview

It's working in SQL-server join query. In C#, I'm calling in data grid view but output isn't as expected ??? It's rough work so leave

1st table Issue book

```
BookId | BooKName | DateIssue| ReturnDate | PersonID
       |          |          |            |
1      | c#       |2007-07-07|2007-07-07  |  105
```

2nd table of Person

```
PersonID | PersonName | PersonType
         |            | 
1        | John       | student
```

Now, I created stored procedure in SQL server...
Query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [database]. [joinIssuetable]
as
select * from table Issue
select * from table Person

Select Book ID,Book Name,Date Issue,Return Date,Person Name
from tableIssue
join tablePerson
  on tableIssue.Person ID = tablePerson.PersonID
```

===========================================================================
calling Join query in C# but data grid view isn't showing output as expected.

```
public void Stored Procedure()
{
  string w = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LMS"].ConnectionString;               
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(w);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("joinIssuetable", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            conn.Open();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Now, I've added code and query... Please help me @tinka!!!

Comment: do you really have your columns like this?

Comment: You need to bind your datagrid. dataGridView1.DataBind();

Comment: As posted your query isn't even close to working because you column names have spaces. Also not really sure what you mean by "output isn't as expected"??? What does that mean? Is the color blue when you expected orange? Is the data scrambled? Are the columns in the wrong order? Is there no data? Help us to help you by providing details about the problem.

Comment: you should put your actual code, not the final decorated output. now that you have your columns displayed correctly, I believe your query is still not updated. also can you provide a screen shot of how your grid is displaying data if at all anything is being displayed?

Comment: @Warda your SP will return 3 different data table

Comment: Databing is giving an error.... @SeanLange

Comment: @Sushil ... I'm new here!!! So, I posted first time!!! Yes My columns are same as in my code I've... Believe me this is correct code... Output expected means: my query is working in SQL server fine but when I'm calling stored procedure as u can see the above code its not showing me the way as in sql server...

Comment: Please correct my code ....

Comment: Warda, you do realize that I can't see your screen right? You are getting an error. Perhaps you could be troubled to share the error message???

Comment: *not showing me the way as in sql server* can you please elaborate a little more on that? first of all you do not have the `DataBind()` on your grid. secondly as @tinka suggested, your procedure is returning 3 tables and most important of all you need to show us what is your output or error. we're all here to help you but only if you help us with what your problem is.

Comment: We can't correct your code because we have no idea what is wrong. I sense there is a language barrier here. That is not a problem, we can work with that. You need to provide details. This is like taking your car to the mechanic and saying "my car is broken, please fix it". You wouldn't do that, you would tell the mechanic what the problem is.

Comment: You might take a look at this link. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx

Comment: BookID | BookName | DateIssue | ReturnDate | PersonID  these r the columns I'm having as output in C#... I want PersonName instead of PersonID. So, I used join query in sql server n called it in C#.. but, It is showing me PersonID not PersonName in datagridview C#.  this is my problem ...

Comment: can you also share your `GridView` code?

Comment: No datagridview code.... I created the stored proc for it... as above mentioned. @Sushil

Comment: @tinka link u provided done by inline query.... My problem is different...

Comment: You STILL haven't provided any information about what the problem is. Here is my last shot in the dark. Do you have the columns defined in your datagrid? If you defined that columns you will need to change that definition. I hope you are able to fix your issue and I hope for your sake you provide some details next time you need help regardless of what forum it is on.

Comment: @SeanLange my problem is solved...  And u can see below answer... I wrote my problem crystal clear... A guy name ' Reza Agaei' told my mistake... ok??

Comment: I beg to differ that your problem was crystal clear. It was easy for you because you knew the problem. If you had said you were getting more columns than you wanted or stated that your grid had x columns but you only wanted some of them to display it would have been clear. Had you provided all of the information this would have been solved in a few minutes and saved lots of aggravation. Glad you were able to get a resolution.

Comment: hmm... Leave it!!! no more concern... Well, Thanks ton for your help... Further, If I got any problem, I would, surely emphasize to make it more clear for programmers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `Select * from ...` in StoredProcedure code. just edit your procedure to have only 1 result set:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [database]. [joinIssuetable]
AS
SELECT BookID, BookName, DateIssue, ReturnDate, Person Name
FROM tableIssue
JOIN tablePerson
ON   tableIssue.PersonID = tablePerson.PersonID
```